# Why do equivalent trig functions differ in values they yield?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, rounding-error

Suppose we are given **[1-cos(x)]/sin(x)**.  Through calculations, we know that this will be equal to **sin(x)/[1+cos(x)]**.  Now, if we assume an angle value, say x=0.006, they will yield  5.235985325*10^-5 and 5.235987761*10^-5, respectively.  As we can see, there is a discrepancy value of **2.436*10^-11**.

My question is, despite the functions being equal, why do their values differ (even though it's small), when we provided an angle value?  Can we say that one value is better than the other?

Comment: Roundoff error in your calculator or software.

Comment: The actual values are the same! What's not the same is what your calculator is telling you. But what your calculator says is just an approximation - here you're getting two different approximations to the same value

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're working in degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't quite the same.  For most values, they are the same (although because of the different method of calculation, a difference due to rounding errors might appear.

However, take for example the value $x=0$.  In this case, $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ is undefined, but $\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$ is zero.  However, if you take the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$, you get $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=0$.  Basically, $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ and $\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$ are the same everywhere that neither has a removable singularity; if one has a removable singularity, it has a limit of $0$, which  is the value of the other at that angle.